# Failed Opening autoload.php in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I have recently installed Laravel via Composer but I keep get the following error:

> Warning:
>   require(/home/leovoon/public_html/laravel-eee/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/leovoon/public_html/laravel-eee/bootstrap/autoload.php on line
>   17
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   '/home/leovoon/public_html/laravel-eee/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/share/pear') in
>   /home/leovoon/public_html/laravel-eee/bootstrap/autoload.php on line
>   17

Am I missing something? Because I followed it step by step.

[image]

Comment: can you provide the screnshot of the directory structure

Comment: @Manojkiran.A added

Comment: give read-write permission to the folder.

Comment: not in the local machine please provide the webserver screenshot

Comment: @Manojkiran.A updated

Comment: I miss the vendor folder on your image....

Comment: @YoramdeLangen after I run composer install command, and the vendor folder has been there. But another error come out which is "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Dotenv\Dotenv' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel-Lumen-API-master\bootstrap\app.php:6"

Comment: [Please prefer text to images/screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Answer (score 14):

You got an error because you have missing **vendor folder** in your project, You need `/vendor` because all your packages are there, including all the classes Laravel uses. The vendor directory contains your Composer dependencies.

Your problem can be resolved after following this step. you can try it:

```
composer update --no-scripts 
composer update
```

With this command, you will re-create the **vendor folder** in your project and after that your project will start working normally.

Answer (score 3):

While Going Live This is my Project Structure

**NOTE:WHILE DOING THIS YOU MAY ENCOUNTER SOME STYLE AND JAVASCRIPT REFERENCE ERROR
IF YOU ARE USNIG `ASSET FUNCTION` NO NEED TO WORRY**

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

**BUT IF NOT IF WILL OCCUR 404 IN SOME CASES**

this is Just For Example

```
Step 1 : create a folder named as `ProjectFiles` in root of your application
```

[image]

```
Step 2: copy all the contents except and folder except `public` folder and paste inside `ProjectFiles` folder
```

[image]

```
Step3: now cut and paste all the contents inside the public folder in root of your application root
```

[image]

step4: open your `index.php` file and make the following changes

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

to

```
require __DIR__.'/ProjectFiles/vendor/autoload.php';
```

AND

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

to

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/ProjectFiles/bootstrap/app.php';
```

and then upload your project to live cpanel server

here is my cpanel server directory structure

hope it helps if the answer is not clear please comment below if the error continues

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I got this error after trying to start the dev server using `php artisan serve`
This is how I resolved it:

1. Run `composer install`

In case you get an error like "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages", make sure you have the necessary extensions enabled in your php.ini config.
In my case I needed to enable `extension=fileinfo`

1. Run `composer update`. After this you should be able to start the server with no errors.

Answer (score 1):

Run composer with --no-scripts

```
composer update --no-scripts
```

This shall fix the issue.

Comment: Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel-Lumen-API-master\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel-Lumen-API-master\bootstrap\app.php on line 3

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel-Lumen-API-master\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' 
(include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel-Lumen-API-master\bootstrap\app.php on line 3

Comment: After run the script, the issue still persists

Answer (score 1):

You must provide Read and write permissions to your project and generate a key in your .env file

Run the following commands inside your project dir and you would be good to go :

```
$ sudo chmod -R 777 /storage /public /bootstrap

$ composer install

$ php artisan key:generate
```

Comment: You should be using 755, not 777!

Answer (score -1):

In my case the issue was a missing extension in my php-cli. Using Ubuntu 23 I had to call `sudo apt install php-curl` then I could call `composer install` and start the server.

Comment: That sounds pretty unsual. If the vendor folder is not present (as shown in the screenshot), it's obvious that loading files from that folder is not possible. Installing cURL won't resolve this

Comment: @NicoHaase in MY case it did resolve that. Missing extensions on PHP can be a problem as composer is writen in PHP and uses cURL for retrieving the package. Rather than just downvoting, please try removing your curl extension, install laravel, try to run it and check if you get the same message or not. That would be more productive.

Comment: Composer will run fine without cURL, and there's no indication in the OP's question that running `composer install` caused any trouble

Comment: @NicoHaase Ok, so according to you, composer comes will all packages available for PHP, with the latest updates. Maybe you should reflect a little bit about it.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it. What should I reflect about, and how does this affect your answer?